# Find the array element that has a certain attribute value

Tags: javascript, arrays

Please consider the below object as example:

```js
let roomsData = [{
  "room_ID": "100",
  "Seats_Available": 4,
  "Amenities": ["AC", "Hot Water"],
  "Price": "10000"
}, {
  "room_ID": "203",
  "Seats_Available": 6,
  "Amenities": ["AC", "Hot Water", "Washing"],
  "Price": "10000"
}, {
  "room_ID": "301",
  "Seats_Available": 4,
  "Amenities": ["Non AC", "Hot Water"],
  "Price": "10000"
}]
```

If we have have `100` as room `ID` (i.e the value) in above example with us then I want to get the output as the complete `array` element like below:

```json
{
  "room_ID": "100",
  "Seats_Available": 4,
  "Amenities": ["AC", "Hot Water"],
  "Price": "10000"
}
```

Can you please explain if there is any solution for that?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2722159/how-to-filter-object-array-based-on-attributes

Comment: Use [`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find). (The linked question does the same with `filter`, returning all matching elements, but since you are looking for only one element anyway, `find` is the better way.)

Comment: There is no JSON in this question. What you have is a JavaScript Object, more specifically a JS Array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick solution is to use [`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) to get the desired item based on an `ID`.

The `find` method loops through your data and returns the first matched element based on a callback function that you supply to it that should return `true` when the desired item is the current one.

Here's a live demo to illustrate all what's being said:

```js
let roomsData = [{
      "room_ID": "100",
      "Seats_Available": 4,
      "Amenities": ["AC", "Hot Water"],
      "Price": "10000"
    },
    {
      "room_ID": "203",
      "Seats_Available": 6,
      "Amenities": ["AC", "Hot Water", "Washing"],
      "Price": "10000"
    },
    {
      "room_ID": "301",
      "Seats_Available": 4,
      "Amenities": ["Non AC", "Hot Water"],
      "Price": "10000"
    }
  ],
  /** 
  * get a room by its ID
  * return the item if found or "undefined" otherwise
  */
  getRoomById = roomID => roomsData.find(i => i.room_ID == roomID);

/** call that function */
console.log(getRoomById(1000));
```

The above code, precisely the call to `getRoomById`, should display:

```json
{
  "room_ID": "100",
  "Seats_Available": 4,
  "Amenities": ["AC", "Hot Water"],
  "Price": "10000"
}
```